# Merging Two Trained Networks for Inferencing Sequentially

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to merge two trained neural networks.
I have two trained Keras model files A and B.

Model A is for image super-resolution and model B is for image colorization.

I am trying to merge two trained networks so that I can inference SR+colorization faster. (I am not willing to use a single network to accomplish both SR and colorization tasks. I need to use two different networks for SR and colorization tasks.)

Any tips on how to merge two Keras neural networks?

Comment: u wanna merge the output?

Comment: I would like to merge two different entire networks into a single network.

Comment: Have you checked this post: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26103/merging-two-different-models-in-keras

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long a the shape of the output of the network A is compatible with the shape of the input of the model B, it is possible.

As a `tf.keras.models.Model` inherits from `tf.keras.layers.Layer`, you can use a `Model` as you would use a `Layer` when creating your keras model.

---

A simple example :

Lets first create 2 simple networks, A and B, with the constraints that the input of B has the same shape as the output of A.

```
import tensorflow as tf 
A = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.Input((10,)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation="tanh")
    ],
    name="A"
)
B = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.Input((5,)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="tanh")
    ],
    name="B"
)
```

Then we can merge those two models as one, in that case using the functional API (this is completely possible using the Sequential API as well):

```
merged_input = tf.keras.Input((10,))
x = A(merged_input)
merged_output = B(x)
merged_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=merged_input, outputs=merged_output, name="merged_AB")
```

resulting in the following network:

```
>>> merged_model.summary()
Model: "merged_AB"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)         [(None, 10)]              0         
_________________________________________________________________
A (Sequential)               (None, 5)                 55        
_________________________________________________________________
B (Sequential)               (None, 10)                60        
=================================================================
Total params: 115
Trainable params: 115
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```