# Tensorflow: export two models in sequence as one

Tags: tensorflow

I have two tensorflow models for two sequential tasks. For some reasons, these two models can't be trained jointly. But now I need to use the output of model 1 as the input of model 2 in prediction stage. Is there anyone who knows how to export these two model in one so that we can get the final output in  one step?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merging Two Trained Networks for Inferencing Sequentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65556636/merging-two-trained-networks-for-inferencing-sequentially)

Comment: The problem is similar, but I use tensorflow instead of Keras, so that the implementation is quite different.

Comment: Then you need to add details to your question. A small example of how your networks are coded, etc.